# Difference between subprocess.call and os.system in python 3

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, wget

I have written a python 3 script to test an API.
The API can only be accessed via a server so I have a bash script to execute `wget` on that server via ssh and move the result to my local machine for analysis. This script works fine on its own.

Now I want to call this bash script from python a few times, however the ssh commands in the bash script seem to break when I use `subprocess.call()`.
This line should save the API response to a chosen location on my server so that I can copy it to my computer later:

```
ssh USER@SERVER.com "wget 'https://API.com/?${options}' -O '${file_path}'"
```

but instead I get the error `bash: -O: command not found` and the response is saved to a default file generated by `wget`:

```
*Using options: 'filter[id]=1234'
*Sending request to API
bash: -O: command not found
--2021-02-19 12:02:52--  https://API.com/?filter[id]=1234

...

Saving to: ‘index.html?filter[id]=1234’

     0K .......... .......... ........                        100% 9.48M=0.003s

2021-02-19 12:02:52 (9.48 MB/s) - ‘index.html?filter[id]=1234.’ saved [29477/29477]
```

So it seems to me that the command being executed via ssh was somehow split into multiple commands?

The weird thing is that when I use `os.system()` to execute the script (or call it directly from the terminal) it works flawlessly. Here is the python code that calls the bash script:

```
# Failing subprocess.call line
subprocess.call(["./get_api.sh", save_file_name, f"'filter[id]={id}'"])

# Succeeding os.system line
system(f"./get_api.sh {save_file_name} 'filter[id]={id}'")
```

I am wondering if anyone can tell me on what might be going on here?

(I edited the included code quite a bit to remove sensitive information, also this is my first stack overflow question so I hope it contains enough information/context)

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes you used in `system` aren't part of the query; they are just part of the shell command that protects `filter[id]={id}` from shell expansion. They should be omitted from the use of `subprocess.call`, which doesn't use a shell.

```
subprocess.call(["./get_api.sh", save_file_name, f"filter[id]={id}"])
```